# DataGridTemplateColumn к автогенерируемым колонкам

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Имеется обычная таблица, которая позволяет автоматически генерировать колонки.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

Мне необходимо добиться того, чтобы все колонки после 1 имели свой DataGridTemplateColumn, что-то вроде:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnN}" Background="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Width="50" Text="{Binding ColumnN}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

ColumnN - определенное имя для колонки, с которым будет происходить связка.
Как этого можно добиться? У меня в принципе и модели нет. Но если есть решение как-нибудь через модель, то тоже может подойдет. Но от автогенерации избавиться не могу.

Comment: Подписывайтесь на событие генерации колонки и подставляйте ей свой шаблон

Comment: @Андрей NOP , у меня не получается нормально binding сделать динамический для templatecolumn.

Comment: Написал ответ, изучайте

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужен `DataGridTemplateColumn`, подойдет обычный `DataGridTextColumn`. Подпишитесь на `AutoGeneratingColumn`, а сами стили положите, например, в ресурсы `DataGrid` (или куда вам удобнее):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ElementStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="EditingElementStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            <!--Это часть стандартного стиля, если она вам нужна-->
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Код подписчика:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    // Здесь проверяем какие столбцы надо проигнорировать, например по имени столбца
    // Проверка e.Column.DisplayIndex здесь не сработает,
    //  т.к. пока столбец не добавлен, он имеет индекс -1
    if (e.PropertyName == "Column1") return;
    // Делаем любые нужные манипуляции с будущим столбцом:
    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    var textColumn = (DataGridTextColumn)e.Column;
    textColumn.ElementStyle = (Style)dataGrid.Resources["ElementStyle"];
    textColumn.EditingElementStyle = (Style)dataGrid.Resources["EditingElementStyle"];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мне нужен именно DataGridTemplateColumn, но я думаю, что с ним будет примерно так же через стили